# Threading doesn't complete the task before ending the thread loop

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, api

So I did something similar a while ago, but this is essentially a username checker for a (specific) website, they can load in usernames via text file and it will put it into a list box, now I have the start button and it's meant to check each username. Before, however, it froze the program when they checked, but it worked. I tried making it "threaded" so it didn't freeze.

The problem now is that it doesn't check them all, and finishes instantly.

CODE:

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Button6.Enabled = False
    Dim goodUsers As New SaveFileDialog()
    goodUsers.Filter = "TXT file (*.txt)|*.txt"
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim Incomplete As Integer = 0
    Dim Taken As Integer = 0
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    If goodUsers.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim checkerMT As New Thread(
            Sub()
                For Each i As String In UsernameList.Items
                    WebRequest.Create("http://yatobooter.cf/other/checkusr.php?username=" + i.ToString)

                    Dim cResult As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://yatobooter.cf/other/checkusr.php?username=" + i.ToString).ToString

                    If cResult = "taken" Then
                        flag = False
                    ElseIf cResult = "nottaken" Then
                        flag = True
                    End If

                    If flag = True Then
                        sb.Append(i & vbNewLine)
                    Else
                        Incomplete = Incomplete + 1
                        Taken = UsernameList.Items.Count - Incomplete
                    End If
                Next
            End Sub
        )
        checkerMT.Start()
        Try
            File.WriteAllText(goodUsers.FileName, sb.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    End If
    MessageBox.Show("Checking available usernames, complete!", "NameSniper Pro")
    Button6.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Well yes... you're starting a thread to build up the `StringBuilder`, but immediately writing the content of the `StringBuilder` to a file, without waiting for the thread to finish. How did you expect that to work? You'd need to put the file writing into the thread as well... and only show a message box that it's complete when it's really finished.

Comment: Also, not the issue here, but `Catch` blocks that completely ignore the exceptions that they've caught are rarely a good idea. They will *not* help you when you're trying to debug future issues and all you know is that e.g. the file didn't actually get written at all.

Comment: Doing `New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(...)` is a memory leak. You should dispose of the `System.Net.WebClient()`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access UI elements (`UsernameList.Items`) from a thread other than the UI. Instead add a background worker to your form to handle the basic threading stuff (progress reporting, finish reporting, exception handling). Pass into this an object that contains the settings your job needs to do its work without interacting with the ui.

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Button6.Enabled = False
    Dim goodUsers As New SaveFileDialog()
    goodUsers.Filter = "TXT file (*.txt)|*.txt"

    If goodUsers.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        'Note: You'll need to add the filenames
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(New State() With {.Names = {}, .FileName = goodUsers.FileName})
    End If

End Sub

Class State
    Public Names As List(Of String)
    Public StringBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Public Incomplete As Integer
    Public Taken As Integer
    Public FileName As String
End Class

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim state = CType(e.Argument, State)
    For Each i As String In state.Names

        Using cli = New System.Net.WebClient()

            Dim cResult = cli.DownloadString("http://yatobooter.cf/other/checkusr.php?username=" + i.ToString).ToString
            If cResult = "nottaken" Then
                state.StringBuilder.Append(i & vbNewLine)
            Else
                state.Incomplete = state.Incomplete + 1
                state.Taken = state.Names.Count - state.Incomplete
            End If

        End Using
    Next
    IO.File.WriteAllText(state.FileName, state.StringBuilder.ToString)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString(), "Error")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Checking available usernames, complete!", "NameSniper Pro")
    End If
    Button6.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

1. The SaveFileDialog can be used as "Using directive"

   2. Why do you create a webrequest on the one hand, and on the other hand use a webclient? That does not make sense at all.
   3. Instead of your strange if condition, write:

   flag = (cResult.Equals("nottaken"))

   4. All code you want to run after the actions you are currently running in your thread have to be in your thread as well, because it is async.
2. You have to invoke if you use user controls within a thread
   and so on..

Please turn Option Strict On and Option Infer Off

There are lots of other things you could do better.
Please remove the webrequest and webclient combination yourself, that does not make sense at all.

Take a look at this, I cleared it a little bit:

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

    Dim Incomplete As Integer = 0
    Dim Taken As Integer = 0
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder

    Using goodUsers As SaveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog()
    goodUsers.Filter = "TXT file (*.txt)|*.txt"

    If not goodUsers.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then Exit Sub
        Dim checkerMT As New Thread(
            Sub()

            Me.invoke(sub()
       Button6.Enabled = False
                For Each i As String In UsernameList.Items
                    WebRequest.Create("http://yatobooter.cf/other/checkusr.php?username=" + i.ToString)

                    Dim cResult As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://yatobooter.cf/other/checkusr.php?username=" + i.ToString).ToString

                    If (cResult.toLower().Equals("nottaken")) Then
                        sb.Append(String.Concat(i , Environment.NewLine)
                    Else
                        Incomplete += 1
                        Taken = UsernameList.Items.Count - Incomplete
                    End If

                Next
                File.WriteAllText(goodUsers.FileName, sb.ToString)
                Button6.Enabled = True
                MessageBox.Show("Checking available usernames, complete!", "NameSniper Pro")
            End Sub)
            End Sub
        )
        checkerMT.IsBackground = True;
        checkerMT.Start()


End Sub
```

Comment: A lot of good points here but you're starting a background thread to immediately invoke it back onto the ui thread.

Comment: How would you do it ?